Multiple Sinks Processing not persisting in Databricks Community Edition
I am just trying to use Rate with Structured Streaming, so as to write to multiple tables names per MicroBatch. I.e. just refreshing multiple sinks logic in prep for some certification, in pyspark.
No errors, but there is no persistence occuring. A while since I looked; must be something basic.
Coding as follows on Databricks Community Edition, no Hive Catalog. Basic stuff.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SimulateKAFKAandMultipleSinks") \
    .getOrCreate()

rate_stream = spark.readStream \
    .format("rate") \
    .option("rowsPerSecond", 1) \
    .load()

message_stream = rate_stream.select(
    (rate_stream["value"] + 1000).alias("message_id"),              
    rate_stream["timestamp"].alias("event_time"),                    
    (concat(lit("T"), rate_stream["value"] % 5)).alias("table_id")   
)

def append_to_parquet(df, table_id):
    table_path = f"/mnt/parquet/{table_id}"   

    df.write \
        .format("parquet") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("path", table_path) \
        .save()

def process_batch(df, batch_id):
    partitioned_df = df.repartition("table_id")
    def process_partition(iterator):
        for partition in iterator:
            first_row_value = df.first()
            table_id_value = first_row_value['table_id']
            print(f"Writing partition for table_id: {table_id_value}") 
            partition_df = partition.filter(col("table_id") == table_id_value)
            append_to_parquet(partition_df, table_id_value)

    partitioned_df.rdd.mapPartitions(process_partition)

query = message_stream.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(process_batch) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/parquet/checkpoints/") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

Update. Oversight my side but educational enough. Can do this with batch KAFKA, not via structured streaming. NB: not strictly speaking correct.

in process_partition you reference df, I do not think it is correct

also, not sure if .rdd is available in streaming df

@AlexanderPavlov. Df is fine. Rdd oversight which is ok with batch kafka. Did not want collect but actually not that bad.

The issue with your code not persisting data likely stems from a couple of fundamental issues with how you're using Structured Streaming in Spark.
try this one
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SimulateKAFKAandMultipleSinks") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create a streaming DataFrame
rate_stream = spark.readStream \
    .format("rate") \
    .option("rowsPerSecond", 1) \
    .load()

# Transform the data
message_stream = rate_stream.select(
    (rate_stream["value"] + 1000).alias("message_id"),
    rate_stream["timestamp"].alias("event_time"),
    concat(lit("T"), (rate_stream["value"] % 5).cast("string")).alias("table_id")
)

# Write to multiple sinks based on table_id
def write_to_multiple_sinks(batch_df, batch_id):
    unique_table_ids = batch_df.select("table_id").distinct().collect()
    for row in unique_table_ids:
        table_id = row["table_id"]
        table_path = f"/mnt/parquet/{table_id}"  # Replace with actual storage path
        table_df = batch_df.filter(col("table_id") == table_id)
        table_df.write.mode("append").parquet(table_path)

query = message_stream.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(write_to_multiple_sinks) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/parquet/checkpoints/") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()


So what are the issues? I chose not to use collect. Will look later when back from dinner. Thx. I will compare for sure.

I think the RDD, is an issue if memory serves correctly

issue is use of collect().

This brings all distinct table_id values to the driver node.
For a large number of table_id values or a high volume of data, this can cause:
a) Out of memory errors on the driver.
b) Network bottlenecks, as executors must send all results to the driver.


dont use RDD, unless you are an expert. Using RDDs breaks optimization opportunities provided by the DataFrame API

also .... Writing in a loop without leveraging Spark's distributed nature wastes resources and time.

I think it is a little more nuanced.

RDD is the issue. Batch kafka ok but not here. I will check later.
